# ASPX to have access but direct URL not

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, iis

I have a problem finding solution to my issue.

I am running IIS8 and building up a script in VB.NET.

The script gives access after certain conditions to "hasaccess.aspx" with embedded PDF. The problem is that the SOURCE CODE still shows the URL so someone could potentially share that URL with person who should not have access.

I am thinking there must be a way for allowing IIS ASPX to have access to the file (so embedding works) but not direct URL (if someone pastes it to address  bar it should give 403 or something)

I found something about "Managing Handlers" but information was so vague that I find really hard to implement that.

I would really appreciate your help with this.

Comment: Do the users log in to the site?

Comment: They are authenticated using Windows Authentication. Based on that I have the username which I compare with DataBase to determine access to hasaccess.aspx otherwise it redirects to noaccess.aspx. Hasaccess.aspx has embeded PDF which is fine but I don't want the users who have access to be able to provide direct URL to users who don't.

Comment: At the moment I workarounded the issue with converting PDF to HTML. I injected the HTML code via runat=server after passing conditions. I wish to find a proper solution which will suffice automation in future.